# Внедрение PHP-кода в HTML-страницу

Tags: php, html

Делаю практически впервые сайт и, так уж получилось, что все страницы php и только одна с расширением html. Есть php код для выделения кнопки меню страницы, на которой находится пользователь. Вопрос такой: можно ли внедрить php код в страницу с расширением html? Я в этом пока не очень хорошо разбираюсь, не судите строго.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте просто расширение PHP и всё =) т.е. index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
<?php

echo 'Hello!';

?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: не выходит, пустая страница...что не так делаю?

Comment: смотрите выше

Comment: в этом то и дело, расширение не хотелось бы менять...

Comment: Тогда AddType text/html нужно будет прописать кой куды=) в .htaccess например. Лучше напрямую в настройки сервера. Предполагаю что у вас апач.

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вашу "проблему" можно решить двумя способами. Первый способ заключается в простом включении PHP кода в страницу:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
<?php

echo 'Hello World!';

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Второй же способ вытекает из того, что возникает непонятность по поводу "внедрения". Как надо внедрять? Через подключение другого файла или простое включение, показанное выше?
Через подключение файла можно так:

```
///файл "include.php"///
print("Hello World!");

////////////////////////

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
<?php

include("include.php");

?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Кроме "include" существует еще три функции подгрузки кода из других файлов:

```
include_once()
require()
require_once()
```

Comment: это с расширением php, а у меня страница с html расширением

Comment: Не понял, что вы хотели имели ввиду...